# how to import the .rep file in informatica power center

Tags: informatica

i am new to pmdesigner(Powercenter designer),
is it possiable to import the .rep file in Powercenter designer,
if yes,
Can any one please help me to import the .rep file in Powercenter designer to view the workflow.

Comment: what is a .rep file?

Comment: it is kind of Repositary backup file

Comment: Then I don't think you can import it in designer. As far as I know you can only import xml exports taken earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, Informatica will accept...While importing file file , just select All_type in document type.Then chose this file and see whether u can able import it or not....